# In python random walker ,how can I set a random starting point instead of setting origin?

Tags: python, random-walk

I'm trying to implement a random walker in python.But I want to set a random starting point instead of initialize the first position.how can i set a random starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you structured the code but generally it does this:

```
import random
x = random.randint(Min_x,Max_x)
y = random.randint(Min_y,Max_y)

[your loop code...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is not here to solve your homework, I do however hope you're trying to achieve this in your free time, so here is the answer:
Use the `random` module like that to generate a random point as your starting point:

```
import random

x_start = random.randint(0,width)
y_start = random.randint(0,height)
```

Based on the poor details you provided, I can not give a more in-depth answer to your question. You might need to adjust the code, so that it fits your screen's coordinate system.